# How to plot a stacked bar chart when data is already aggregated

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i have a dataframe that looks like the below. 
i want to plot something like a stacked bar chart where each layer of the stack is the listing neighborhood count. Thing is, i already aggregated the count for each listing.

[image]

[image]

I want something like this the above

But the chart size should be different for each color and the y-axis should be count. 
my code:

```
df.groupby(['country','listing_neighborhood']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

I also tried:

```
df.plot(x='country',y='count',stacked=True,kind='bar')
```

But i want them stacked but it doesnt seem to work

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df.pivot('country','listing_neighborhood','count').plot(stacked=True, kind='bar')
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by drawing bars which are equal to the sum of the groups it's stacked on top of and itself:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_bars(lst, colors, ax, position, width):
    for i in range(len(lst), 0, -1):
        # plot a bunch of rectangles on top of each other
        # each rectangle is equal to to the cumulative including that block
        rects1 = ax.bar(position, sum(lst[:i]), width, color=colors[i%len(lst)])

AR = [250, 218, 108]
AU = [90, 86, 38]
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plot_bars(AR, colors, ax, 1, 0.5)
plot_bars(AU, colors, ax, 2, 0.5)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ECft.png)?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"country":["AR","AR","AR","AU","AU","AU"],
                   "listing_neighborhood":["-unknown-","Copacabana","Ipanema","-unknown-","Copacabana","Ipanema"],
                   "count":[250,218,108,90,86,38]})
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, values="count", index="country", columns="listing_neighborhood", aggfunc=np.sum)
pt.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```